# Get class with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

```
<span class="here one-two-sdfs test">click1</span> <br />
<span class="here one-two-3er te3st">click2</span> <br />
<span class="here one-two-sdwrer test">click3</span> <br />
<span class="here one-two-s-ere test">click4</span> <br />
<span class="here one-two-wer-r test">click5</span> <br />
<span class="here one-two test">click6</span> <br />

$('.here').click(function(){
    var one-two = ????
    alert(one-two);
    })​
```

​
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tMzAH/)

i would like -

if i click on **click1** then alert show me **one-two-sdfs**

if i click on **click2** then alert show me **one-two-3er**

if i click on **click3** then alert show me **one-two-sdwrer**

if i click on **click4** then alert show me **one-two-s-ere**

if i click on **click5** then alert show me **one-two-wer-r**

if i click on **click6** then alert show me **one-two**

i would like show class with begin **one-two-**
how can i make it?:)

Comment: Did you try doing any reading on regular expressions and work yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/tMzAH/10/

```
$('.here').click(function(){
    var onetwo = this.className.match(/\bone-two[^\s]*/);
    console.log(onetwo[0]);
})
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you chose `[^\s]` over `\S`?

Comment: @phant0m: I think it's more of "It works for me so I accept".

Comment: @nhahtdh I meant F. Calderan, not the OP :)

Comment: @phant0m: Oh, I thought you were referring to OP.

Comment: @phant0m not really, I just wrote what came in my mind "I need to match one-two plus some optional not-blank character" :) \S is fine and shorter

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/S4k5p/) should work.

```
$('.here').click(function(){
    var one_two = $(this).attr("class").match(/\bone-two\S*/)[0];
    alert(one_two);
    })​
```

Comment: This may fail if the class is `one-two-three-four`, since `\w` doesn't match `-`. I think `\S*` is better.

Answer (score 0):

Get the className of the element you clicked. And then split it.
You do not need RegEx for this ;)